# PowerShell Task Scheduler - Trigger Task at different hours of the day

Tags: powershell

I have a Standalone managed service account that is running some tasks but i would like to be able for a specific task to be run at set times of the day.
For example. i would need a task to run every weekday at 07:00, 14:55, 15:25 and 17:15

How can i add more than 1 trigger to that service account via powershell as i am unable to make changes via the GUI with a service account?

Thank you

I have tried to create multiple triggers (one trigger per variable) but when running Register-ScheduledTask it only accepts one variable as a Trigger

Comment: To add multiple arguments to trigger use an array of triggers as arguments. `-Trigger (New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -At 07:00 -Daily), (New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -At 14:55 -Daily), (New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -At 15:25 -Daily), (New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -At 17:15 -Daily)`

Answer (score 0):

You can create more the one task to run instead of creating one task with more than one trigger. It's basically the same.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).